# React: react-bootstrap button

Tags: reactjs, button, react-bootstrap

this is a rather odd problem, it is to do with the button

for my onClick function, i am passing a value through it, sometimes i would get an undefined value, and sometimes i will get a defined value

Upon further inspection, i realised, when i was not clicking on the text of the button, a value would be returned, but when i am clicking on the text of the button, it returns an undefined value

```
 <Button value = {"test"} style={{ marginTop: 30, marginRight: 30, float: "right" }} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={e => this.addrow(e)}>
                    Add New Row
 </Button>
```

above is my code for my button, my function is binded in the constructor.

Is there any way to resolve the above issue? such that a value will always be produced, regardless of whether i am clicking on the text in the button or not

edit:
1. added my code for the addrow function

```
addrow(e) {
        // window.localStorage.removeItem("userId");
        // this.props.history.push('/add-user');
        console.log("button pressed", e.target.value)
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more code snippet.

Comment: @Stanjhae what code snipper do u need? i have provided the add row function

Answer (score 0):

how are you getting the value from the event? Can you share the `addrow` code?

I tried this and don't find any difference clicking in the text or not.

```
  addrow = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
```

Some example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-x9djh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: hmm thats strange, because all im doing is simply console logging e.target.value :/

Comment: yeah I don't know what may be causing what you are saying. One more thing, you could call the function like this on Button `onClick={this.addrow}`